# How to preparing theme for new users? Export ready theme

Tags: themes, export

I'm working on the WordPress theme, I want to ask how to do the demo content, how to EXPORT the all - menu, pictures, texts, widgets, everything? I also made require download plugins whit TGM Plugin with which the theme works, but how to do when installing the theme, these plugins to come with my custom settings from the original theme? Most simply how to make a theme ready for installation by another user as it looks in the demo version?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [One Click Demo Import](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/one-click-demo-import/) plugin

Answer (score 0):

Use theme demo import plugin to import all files
https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-demo-import/